# Smoothly scroll element from current position

Tags: javascript, smooth-scrolling

I have written the following code to scroll an element 20 more pixels to the right.

```
const button = document.getElementById('slide');

button.onclick = function () {
  document.getElementById('container').scrollLeft += 20;
};
```

How can I make the scrolling smooth? I have tried using `Element#scroll` like so:

```
const button = document.getElementById('slide');

button.onclick = function () {
  document.getElementById('container').scroll({
      left: += 20,
      behavior: smooth
  });
};
```

Am I able to do this?

Comment: Just change the `left: += 20` to `left: 20` and put quotes around smooth

Comment: @Steve That wouldn't increase the position by 20 each time.

Comment: I didn't see that you changed the OP to move it 20 more pixels on each click. Then use: `document.getElementById('container').scrollBy({left:20, behavior: 'smooth'})`

Comment: @Steve I didn't change the meaning of the post. It's clear from the first code snippet: `document.getElementById('container').scrollLeft += 20;`

Comment: @Unmitigated Please remember that it is important to have a good, clear explanation, which DID change to a more descriptive explanation about the same time I posted the comment (just look at the history of the post). While the "meaning of the post" may be clear in your head, those that are trying to help don't have the same full picture of what you are trying to accomplish when the explanation is not clear.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`Element#scrollBy`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollBy) to scroll a certain amount from the current position.

```js
button.onclick = function () {
  document.getElementById('container').scrollBy({
      left: 20,
      behavior: 'smooth'
  });
};
```

Comment: This is not accurate because it always sets the `scrollLeft` to 20 each time the user clicks on the button. So It will no longer scroll after first click.

Comment: @Medteck That is not true. Did you read the explanation in my answer? `Element#scroll` is not the same as `Element#scrollBy`. See the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollBy). Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/x7gv3moz/

Comment: My bad! I misread that part. I'm removing my downvote.

Answer (score -1):

Is this what you are looking for?

From MDN:

> `scrollBy()` scrolls by a particular amount, whereas `scroll()` scrolls to an absolute position in the document.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/scrollBy

```js
const container = document.querySelector("#container");
const button = document.querySelector("#btnScroll");

button.addEventListener('click', e => {
  container.scrollBy({
    left: 200,
    behavior: 'smooth'
  });
});
```

```css
#container {
  position: relative;
  max-width: 200px;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  display: flex;
  margin: 20px;
}

img {
  display: inline-block
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <img src="https://dummyimage.com/200x100/000/fff">
  <img src="https://dummyimage.com/200x100/0f0/000">
  <img src="https://dummyimage.com/200x100/00f/fff">
  <img src="https://dummyimage.com/200x100/f00/fff">
</div>
<button id="btnScroll">Scroll 200px</button>
```